# Only return the highest value in each group oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

Given a table:

```
NAME        DATE_OCCURRED
a           2020-05-14 23:48.07
a           2020-05-14 23:48.07
a           2020-05-14 23:48.08
b           2020-05-14 23:48.08
b           2020-05-14 23:48.08
b           2020-05-14 23:48.08
b           2020-05-14 23:48.09
```

I would like to return, for each `NAME`, the time at which the most records exist; and how many records exist at that time:

```
NAME       MAXCOUNT_PER_SECOND   DATE_OCCURRED
a          2                     2020-05-14 23:48.07
b          3                     2020-05-14 23:48.08
```

I have found the SQL to group the count by DATE_OCCURRED and NAME:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT_PER_SECOND, NAME, DATE_OCCURRED FROM TABLE GROUP BY NAME, DATE_OCCURRED ORDER BY NAME ASC, COUNT_PER_SECOND DESC`

but I now want to select again, picking just the max for each name. I have tried:

`SELECT MAX(COUNT_PER_SECOND) AS MAXCOUNT_PER_SECOND, NAME FROM (the above query) GROUP BY NAME;` and that works to give me the `MAXCOUNT_PER_SECOND` and the `NAME`; but as soon as I try and also get which `DATE_OCCURRED` resulted in that `MAXCOUNT_PER_SECOND` value, I end up with grouping errors when running the SQL; or I don't get the results I expect.

i.e:

`SELECT MAX(COUNT_PER_SECOND) AS MAXCOUNT_PER_SECOND, NAME, DATE_OCCURRED FROM (the above query) GROUP BY NAME;` -> `Not a GROUP BY expression`

`SELECT MAX(COUNT_PER_SECOND) AS MAXCOUNT_PER_SECOND, NAME, DATE_OCCURRED FROM (the above query) GROUP BY NAME, DATE_OCCURRED ;` -> Runs, but gives me the results for all dates, instead of just the max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggreagation and window functions:

```
select name, date_occured, no_records
from (
    select 
        name, 
        date_occured, 
        count(*) no_records, 
        rank() over(partition by name order by count(*) desc) rn
    from mytable
    group by name, date_occured
) t
where rn = 1
```

The subquery aggreagates by `name` and `date_occured`, counts the records per group, and ranks groups of records having the same `name` by descending count. Then the outer query filters on the top record per `name`. Since we use `rank()`, possible top ties will be included in the resultset (if you don't want that, use `row_number()` instead).